# Trying to send an email using express and nodemailer and literally nothing is showing up in the console or the terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemailer, mailhog

trying to get it so that when the send email button is clicked it sends it to a mailhog inbox, but it is literally doing nothing, not even any console errors or anything in the terminal. What I'm trying to do is to send the name, email, chosen plan and message from the form to the mailhog address using nodemailer, however when i click the send button, nothing shows up in the terminal or the browser console, all it does is indent the url with the code when i've got it set up with the rest of the things on my website.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
  <section id="contact" class="fade-in">
    <h2>Contact Us</h2>
    <p>Let's discuss your project! Fill out the form below.</p>
    <form id="contactForm" onsubmit="submitOrder(event)" >
      <!-- Your form fields here -->
      <!-- Example: -->
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required>
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" required>
      <input type="text" name="chosen-plan" id="chosen-plan" placeholder="Chosen Plan" required>
      <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your Message" rows="4" required></textarea>
      <button id="msg-btn">
        <div class="svg-wrapper-1">
          <div class="svg-wrapper">
            <svg height="24" width="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
              <path d="M1.946 9.315c-.522-.174-.527-.455.01-.634l19.087-6.362c.529-.176.832.12.684.638l-5.454 19.086c-.15.529-.455.547-.679.045L12 14l6-8-8 6-8.054-2.685z" fill="currentColor"></path>
            </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
        <span>Send Message</span>
      </button>
    </form>
  </section>

  <footer>
    <div class="container">
      <p>footer/p>
    </div>
  </footer>
<script>
  async function submitOrder(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission and page reload

    console.log('Function executed');

    // Get customer details from the form
    const nameInput = document.getElementById('name');
    const emailInput = document.getElementById('email');
    const chosenPlanInput = document.getElementById('chosen-plan');
    const messageInput = document.getElementById('message');

    const name = nameInput.value;
    const email = emailInput.value;
    const chosenPlan = chosenPlanInput.value;
    const message = messageInput.value;

    console.log('Customer:', { name, email, chosenPlan, message });

    // You can add more fields to the customer object if needed
    const customer = {
      name,
      email,
      chosenPlan,
      message,
    };

    try {
      // Send the data to the server
      const response = await fetch('/send-email', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ customer }),
      });

      console.log('Response:', response);

      if (response.ok) {
        // Email sent successfully
        console.log('Email sent successfully');
        // Handle any further actions or display success message if needed
      } else {
        // Error sending email
        console.error('Error sending email');
        // Handle error if needed
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error sending email:', error);
      // Handle error if needed
    }
  }

  const sendButton = document.getElementById('msg-btn');
  sendButton.addEventListener('click', submitOrder);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

sendEmail.js:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
async function sendEmail(customer) {
  try {
    // Create a Nodemailer transporter with SMTP credentials
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 1025,     });

    // Construct the email message
    const message = {
      from: 'noreply@mailhog.example', 
      to: 'example@mailhog.example', 
      subject: 'New Contact Request',
      html: `
        <h3>Contact Request</h3>
        <p>Name: ${customer.name}</p>
        <p>Email: ${customer.email}</p>
        <p>Chosen Plan: ${customer.chosenPlan}</p>
        <p>Message: ${customer.message}</p>
      `,
    };

    // Send the email
    const info = await transporter.sendMail(message);
    console.info('Email sent:', info.messageId);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error sending email:', error);
    throw error; // Re-throw the error to be caught in the calling function (in your server file)
  }
}

module.exports = sendEmail;
```

server.js:

```
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const sendEmail = require('./sendEmail'); // Import the Nodemailer function

const app = express();
const PORT = 3000; // Choose a suitable port number

// Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Enable CORS
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.static('pb'));
app.get('*', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    res.status(200);
    res.send();
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});

// POST endpoint for receiving order details and sending email
app.post('/send-email', async (req, res) => {
  console.log('Received POST request:', req.body); // Add this line to check the received data

  const { customer } = req.body;

  // Check if 'order' and 'customer' objects are present in the request body
  if (!customer) {
    res
      .status(400)
      .send('Invalid request: "customer" objects are required.');
    return;
  }

  // Check if 'name', 'email', and 'phone' properties are present in the 'customer' object
  if (!customer.name || !customer.email) {
    res
      .status(400)
      .send(
        'Invalid request: "name", "email" properties are required in the "customer" object.',
      );
    return;
  }

  const payload = { ...customer };
  try {
    // Send the email using the sendEmail function with the payload
    await sendEmail(payload);

    res.status(200).send('Email sent successfully');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error sending email:', error);
    res.status(500).send('Error sending email');
  }
});

// Error handling middleware
app.use((req, res) => res.status(404).send('Not Found'));
app.use((err, req, res) => {
  console.error('Unhandled error', err);
  res.status(500);
  res.send(JSON.stringify(err));
});

// Start the server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.info(`Server started on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the config in transporter in your sendEmail.js file

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "Gmail",
    auth: {
          user: "******@gmail.com",
          pass: "gmail_password"
        }
});
```

You have to provide the credentials from which email you are going to send mail.

If you want a more secure option that doesn't expose your password, you can look at this blog https://dev.to/chandrapantachhetri/sending-emails-securely-using-node-js-nodemailer-smtp-gmail-and-oauth2-g3a